# Cosine angle calculation for the documents - Dissimilarity function not working in tm package in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I want to find the document similarity.

I am using the below R code

## read 1000 txt articles from directory data/txt

corpus  <-Corpus(DirSource("data/txt"), readerControl = list(blank.lines.skip=TRUE));

## some preprocessing

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument, language="english")

## creating term matrix with TF-IDF weighting

terms <-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE)))

## or compute cosine distance among documents

dissimilarity(tdm, method = "cosine")

It seems dissimilarity function is not supported by the tm package any more. Is there a way to find the cosine angle between the documents. (Rows are documents, columns are texts. So i want to find the similarity between the rows using cosine angle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using an alternative package, **quanteda**, that has a function called `similarity()`.  It's still a bit rough around the edges but works as advertised.

```
require(quanteda)
# clean the texts and create a document-feature matrix
myDfm <- dfm(inaugCorpus, verbose = FALSE)
# similarity matrix for cosine
similarity(myDfm, docnames(myDfm), margin = "documents", method = "cosine")
```

The last command produces a list of numeric vectors of cosine similarity where each list element corresponds to a document (supplied by `docnames(myDfm)`).  If you wanted to focus on just a single document, you can name just one.

To load the files you want, you can use (might need adjustment for your example):

```
myCorpus <- corpus(textfile("data/txt/*txt"))
```

Comment: Does cosine angle calculated based on TF-IDF values?

Comment: It does not by default, but you can use `weight(myDfm, "tfidf")` to change the dfm object to tfodf weights, and then compute the cosine distances on that.

Comment: @KenBenoit what is inaugCorpus data type in your code, I tried to put my Corpus object  but gives me error saying    ` Error in UseMethod("dfm") : 
  no applicable method for 'dfm' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'list')"`